# Backend for Matplotlib not changing from TkAgg to GR

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to change the backend of `matplotlib` to `GR` so I can plot faster. When I use the `matplotlib.use('GR')` function. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 'gr' is not a valid value for backend; supported values are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'Qt4Agg', 'Qt4Cairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']
```

I had pip installed `GR`  and made sure the backend file exists in my `Python` directory. My question is how can I change the backend of `matplotlib` to `GR` without it giving me this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
matplotlib.use("module://gr.matplotlib.backend_gr")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I tried this method and it gives me the following error: "OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000209DE63C000". Any idea what this means? I tried googling it but can't find much documentation on this.

Comment: have you installed the `gr` module? Use `pip install gr` if you haven't

Comment: I installed both the `gr` and used `pip install gr`. Now it doesn't give me the before mentioned error but open and closes the figure really quickly. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: About quickly opening and closing figures, does this help  https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1865 ? This is about julia but maybe something similar is happening in your case.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your issue, you can just save the figure as image and then see them.

Comment: Hi just wanted to let you know that's what I ended up doing. Thank you

Comment: Oh no problem, Happy to help, maybe you can accept this answer if this helped you?